# Getting in-memory size of an object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, memory-leaks

I've got a (long-running) script that I'm trying execute. Unfortunately, as it runs, the memory usage of powershell begins to creep up. The script is relatively simple, and I can't see any obvious memory leaks. However, I am using an API which may be poorly behaved.

Is there an easy way to get the in-memory size of an object from within powershell, so I can see if my suspicions are correct?

Comment: What kind of API are you using ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps a crude way to do would be something like this:

```
$memBefore = (Get-Process -id $pid).WS
# Create object here...
$memAfter = (Get-Process -id $pid).WS
($memAfter - $memBefore) / 1KB
```

If it is a memory leak you might be able to mitigate it with:

```
[gc]::Collect()
```

Comment: Managed to hack something together... Turned out the API did have a memory leak, but I was able to get around it once I found the culprit. Thanks!

Comment: I think [gc]::Collect() is a godsend for when working with Powershell.. Andy, do you mind if I ask if was this a 3rd-party COM object, or something part of the Windows OS / .NET?

Comment: @indifferentDrum `[gc]` is a built-in type. I've had to use to solve [this third-party library issue](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/12727) which deals with open files.

Answer (score 6):

Another approx way:

```
$before = [gc]::GetTotalMemory($true)
$s = "A new string object"
$after = [gc]::GetTotalMemory($true)

($after - $before)/1kb # return the delta in KBytes
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks right, from reddit.  At least for simple types.

```
using namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices
$tmp = 1234567890 # int32
[Marshal]::SizeOf($tmp)

4


$tmp = 12345678900 # int64
[Marshal]::SizeOf($tmp)

8


$tmp = 12345678900000000000 # decimal
[Marshal]::SizeOf($tmp)

16


[Marshal]::SizeOf

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static int SizeOf(System.Object structure)
static int SizeOf(type t)
static int SizeOf[T](T structure)
static int SizeOf[T]()
```